# LLDB How to set breakpoint whch stops when register == somevalue?

Tags: debugging, lldb

How to set breakpoint in lldb whch stops when register == somevalue
(rdi = 0x0000000000000000)? Is It possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lldb expression parser provides `$rdi`, `$rsi`, etc as convenience variables for register values.  So:

```
(lldb) break modify -c "$rdi == 0x0000000000000000" <BKPT_NO>
```

will do the job.  You can also specify the -c (i.e. --condition) option when you set the breakpoint.

Note, for architectures that pass arguments in registers, lldb also has "$arg1", "$arg2" etc.  These are just aliases for the ABI-specified argument passing registers, so if you're somewhere in the middle of a function they won't hold the argument values anymore.  But for setting breakpoint on the beginning of a function they can come in handy.

Comment: What about when you don't have the function name @Jim Ingham?  I filed a bug with all the details: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47758

Comment: This is a bit harder.  Watchpoints don't help because they are for the data bus, and hardware breakpoints are address not instruction content based, so they don't help either.  As I said in the bug, you can try writing a custom breakpoint resolver that scans the disassembly for syscalls, and sets breakpoints on the address of all the syscalls you find.  You might have to do some filtering, but that should get you started.

Comment: is $rdi a synonym to any register ? If yes then what's for the $rsi ?

Comment: It's the other way round.  $rdi is the real register name on x86_64.  But lldb has $argN aliases for the argument passing registers, so $arg1 is an alias for $rdi on x86_64 and $arg2 is an alias for $rsi.

Comment: This doesn't work with LLDB in 2024. 
error: stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 1.1:

Comment: If you are doing this in a swift frame, the expression will fail because swift doesn't have a natural representation for register values, so they aren't available in the swift expression parser.  That is a known issue.  But lldb's CI has tests for this feature in the C family of languages, so it's unlikely to be broken altogether.  So If your condition isn't on a swift frame, you will need to be more specific for us to be able to help.  Maybe file an issue with lldb's issues tracker: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues.